# Add onclick event to webcharts3d chart?

Tags: coldfusion, charts, onclick

I am using webcharts3d to create a gauge graph for my webpage. I want to add an onclick event to the chart- any idea how to do that?

Here is my code:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="chartStyle">
<!--- xml chart style --->
</cfsavecontent>
<cfsavecontent variable="chartModel"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XML type="default">
<COL>2000</COL>
<cfoutput><ROW col0="#url.rating#">Sample 0:</ROW></cfoutput>
</XML></cfsavecontent>

<cfscript>
   oMyWebChart = createObject("Java","com.gp.api.jsp.MxServerComponent");
   oMyApp = getPageContext().getServletContext();
   oSvr = oMyWebChart.getDefaultInstance(oMyApp);
   oMyChart2 = oSvr.newImageSpec();
   oMyChart2.width = 120;
   oMyChart2.height= 120;
   oMyChart2.type = "swf"; 
   oMyChart2.style = "#chartStyle#";
   oMyChart2.model = "#chartModel#";
</cfscript>

<cfsavecontent variable="chartImgTag">
   <cfoutput>#oSvr.getImageTag(oMyChart2,"http://myWebsite.com/CFIDE/GraphData.cfm?graphCache=wc50&graphID=")#</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>

  <cfoutput>
  #chartimgtag#
 </cfoutput>
```

Comment: Like for a hyperlink? Some chart models have an "action" attribute, though I do not see one for gauge charts. If not, what about wrapping the chart in an anchor tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was setting the chart type to png instead of swf. Then I was able to surround it with an anchor tag.

```
oMyChart2.type = "png";
```

instead of

```
oMyChart2.type = "swf";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **URL** event in cfchart. You can check it out.

Comment: Yes, but cfchart does not support gauge charts directly afaik. That is why they are using the code above and not cfchart tags.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, keeping the oMyChart2.type = "swf";

```
<!--- Extract the style from the WCP file --->
<cfset wcp = XMLParse( ExpandPath("reports/pie.wcp") )>
<cfset wcp.project.style.pieChart.elements.XmlAttributes.action = "javascript:alert('$(colLabel)')">
<cfset chartStyle = ToString(wcp.project.style.pieChart)>
```

Comment: sorry i overlooked that the OP is using a Gauge not Pie.